# Is there PostgreSQL profile file like .bash_profile

Tags: postgresql

Everytime I enter PostgreSQL via Terminal (by "psql"), I have to run some certain meta commands, like "\pset null [null]".
So, is there any way to execute it automatically everytime I run "psql", just like the .bash_profile or .bashrc file in the bash shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in  man psql:

```
~/.psqlrc
```

Comment: Oh, so cool! I didn't see that file (I only saw .psql_history, so I know I will have to create on) in my home directory. I forgot to check the man page.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, finally I found a solution via the help information, edit my .bash_profile, add the line:

```
alias psql='psql --pset=null=[null]'
```

It works